# Prevent Scrapy from generate empty file when there are no results

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Is there a way to prevent scrapy from genrate an empty file when no results yielded from a scrapy spider?

Example usage

```
scrapy crawl lorem -o /path/to/lorem.json
```

Versions used:

- Python 3.6.0
- Scrapy 1.3.0

Comment: In addition, [Issue 2258](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2258) is somewhat relevant. The issue addresses on empty JSON array, but does not prevent empty file been created.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack but you can simply delete the file if it's empty.
This could be achieved in a single command in bash:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o test.json && if ! cat test.json; then rm test.json; fi
```

You could even set up an alias for it.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround suggestion. In between of getting FileFeedStorage solution to work, I've tested out your solution and ended up using `[ -s test.json ] || rm test.json` as a separate bash command, which works.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to write custom feed storage class based on [FileFeedStorage](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#L79) to implement lazy opening of the file when first item is scraped - default FileFeedStorage creates file on start. Then activate it in `settings.py`:

```
FEED_STORAGES = {
    '': 'path.to.CustomFileFeedStorage',
    'file': 'path.to.CustomFileFeedStorage',
}
```

Comment: I've had a look of FileFeedStorage implementatio, especially the `03ab0772491c61cb7f2198b2c019c7eb7672a331` commit for inspiration. However I'm still having trouble coming up with a working solution that allows me to lazy opening the target file path. Can you shed some light? Thanks.